# Import dynamic text file into svelte?

Tags: import, vite, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have about 50 text files containing SVG paths that need to be parsed in ParseSvg.svelte.

+page.svelte

```
<script>
  import ParseSvg from "../components/widgets/ParseSVG.svelte"; 
  let hex = "#c412dd";
  let src = 'w1815'
</script>

<ParseSvg {hex} {src} />
```

ParseSVG.svelte

Hardcoded works perfectly:

```
import src from "$lib/svg/w1815.svg?raw";
```

I've tried:

```
export let src;

 function getSVGUrl(src) {
        return new URL( /* @vite-ignore */ `/src/lib/svg/${src}.svg?raw`, import.meta.url).href;
      }
    
    
const s = getSVGUrl(src)
  
console.log(s)
```

Console Log Produces:

```
file:///src/lib/svg/w1815.svg
```

Trying this:

```
const s2 = import(s);
```

Produces this error:

```
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When constructing a URL and just using that, this code will not be processed by Vite at all. For that to work you have to manually [include your static assets](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#assetsinclude) or (in the case of SvelteKit) put them in the `/static` directory which is already included.

When doing this you also will *not* have access to the file contents directly (`?raw` will do nothing), so if you want to access the contents you first have to load the file, e.g. using `fetch`.

If you want to use a dynamic `import` instead, you have to follow certain rules. Vite uses [a rollup plugin](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars) to support this, which comes with various [limitations](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations). One of them is that paths have to be relative, another is that a file extension has to be specified (please see the documentation for the full list so you do not miss anything).

As an example given these files:

```
+page.svelte
svg.svelte
svg-1.svg
svg-2.svg
```

The page could use the `svg.svelte` component to reference one of the SVGs via its suffix:

```html
<script>
    import Svg from './svg.svelte';
</script>
<Svg source="1" />
<Svg source="2" />
```

Then the component could dynamically import the given file and simply output it as HTML:

```html
<script>
    export let source;
</script>

{#await import(`./svg-${source}.svg?raw`) then { default: svg }}
    <span>{@html svg}</span>
{/await}
```

(For further processing, the file should be imported in an async function in the script.)